# Extract data from fired event

Tags: c#, node.js, events, xamarin.forms

In my `Xamarin.Forms` app I use a `socket.IO` library that fetches data from a Node.js server but I don‘t know about extracting the data from my result. The example method looks like this:

```
socket.On("event", (data) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(data);
});
```

When the result is a simple string, I can directly use it as in the console function above. 
But how do I extract the data when the result is a unknown datatype that contains multiple information, like this?

```
let send = {'firstString': string1, 'secondString': string2}
```

I guess a way could be to make the result a JSON object and read it out by it‘s keys but I don‘t know if that’s a good way and how this would be done.

Comment: in your example `send` is clearly json, so I would imagine you need to use a json parser to parse and extract the values from `data` on receipt.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: No unfortunately, I don’t. Do you have a suggestion how to do so, or some sites to read about it referring to that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) to parse the json

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(data);

var first = obj["firstString"].Value;
var second = obj["secondString"].Value;
```

Comment: Perfect, that looks good and works for me! Thank you very much!